# PhpStorm has stopped underlining undefined variables - how can I turn this back on?

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm (version 9.0.2) no longer underlines undefined variables in yellow. I am not sure why. Misspelled variables are still underlined (in green).

I have checked the settings in Settings/Editor/Inspections, then under PHP/Undefined/undefined variables that these are set up to be flagged as warnings.

In the editor, I can hover over an undefined variable and it brings up the warning.

EDIT:

Here is what my IDE looks like. Having set up Inspections, `$b` should be underlined.

[image: $b should be underlined]

Comment: Please let me know about your PhpStorm version.

Comment: Hi, the version is 9.0.2

Comment: PhpStorm 2018.3 EAP
Build #PS-183.2635.12
Same problem

Answer (score 1):

Please Go to File->Setting->Editor->Code Style->Inspecation->PHP->Undefined
and check to 'undefined'.

[image]

Comment: Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In the PhpStorm in window with open PHP file get on right side, bottom, is small figure of worker, click on it and set left slider (PHP) to high position to PHP Inspections.

[image: PhpStorm .. PHP file edit .. Worker icon on right side bottom]